# How do I import a named SystemJS module from a bundle file?

Tags: javascript, jspm, systemjs

I've got one file (app.js) with two named modules in it ("foo", and "bar" - where "bar" depends on "foo").

Question: How to I load "bar" it in the browser?

Disclaimer: I'm new to SystemJS and the docs look a little intimidating.

*app.js*

```
System.register("foo", [], function(exports_1) {
    "use strict";
    var App;
    return {
        setters:[],
        execute: function() {
            App = (function () {
                function App() {
                    this.bar = 'Hello world.';
                    console.log(this.bar);
                }
                return App;
            })();
            exports_1("App", App);
            ;
        }
    }
});

System.register("bar", ["foo"], function(exports_1) {
    "use strict";
    var App;
    return {
        setters:[],
        execute: function() {
            App = (function () {
                function App() {
                    this.bar = 'Mony a mickle maks a muckle.';
                    console.log(this.bar);
                }
                return App;
            })();
            exports_1("App", App);
            ;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried `System.import('bar').then((module) => {})`?

Comment: Right! It works. I've added the `<script src="app.js">` tag to my index file and `System.import('bar')`.

Answer (score 1):

Got the results I wanted by doing the following:

- Added the `<script src="app.js">` tag to my index file.
- Also added `System.import('bar');` to the page.

I wonder if this is the standard/recommended way of doing it.

Edit:

The issue with this approach is that I need two strategies for development and production.

In development I don't add the `<script>` tag and I import the module using `System.import('path/app.js');`

Comment: You probably still need to consume the module (using the promise that import returns). If it logs right now this is due to the fact that your IIFE will be executed, but the module's export will still not be available to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I think using a bare bones seed can help you out by showing a simple working example, this seed has a PRODUCTION and DEV MODE and you dont need to have 2 strategies, just choose between running it bundled or not

try:
`npm i -g slush-jspm-react-seed`